# Magento 2 - Fulltext search Product SKU / Product Name in Sales Order Grid

Tags: grid, sales, sku, fulltext

I'm a newbie, new to magento 2. Please guide me here: I want to search fulltext product sku and product id in grid order. I have now added the product sku and product id to the grid, the filter is also running, but I don't know how to search the fulltext for these two fields (specifically, search on the "Search by keyword" box). Anyone have any direction, please guide me.

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © MageWorx. All rights reserved.
* See LICENSE.txt for license details.
*/

namespace KhoiNguyenh\Order\Plugin;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OrderGridCollection;

/**
* Class AddDataToOrdersGrid
*/
class KhoiNguyenhAddDataToOrderGrid
{
/**
* @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
*/
private $logger;

/**
* AddDataToOrdersGrid constructor.
*
* @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $customLogger
* @param array $data
*/
public function __construct(
\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $customLogger,
array $data = []
) {
$this->logger = $customLogger;
}

/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject
* @param OrderGridCollection $collection
* @param $requestName
* @return mixed
*/
public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
{
if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
return $collection;
}

if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_grid')) {
try {
// Add product's name column
$this->addProductsDataColumn($collection);
} catch (\Zend_Db_Select_Exception $selectException) {
// Do nothing in that case
$this->logger->log(100, $selectException);
}
}

return $collection;
}

/**
* Adds products number column to the orders grid collection
*
* @param OrderGridCollection $collection
* @return OrderGridCollection
*/
private function addProductsDataColumn(OrderGridCollection $collection): OrderGridCollection
{
// Get original table name
$orderItemsTableName = $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_item');
// Create new select instance
$itemsTableSelectGrouped = $collection->getConnection()->select();
// Add table with columns which must be selected (skip useless columns)
$itemsTableSelectGrouped->from(
$orderItemsTableName,
[
'product_id' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product_id SEPARATOR \',\')'),
'product_sku' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sku SEPARATOR \',\')'),
'order_id' => 'order_id'
]
);
// Group our select to make one column for one order
$itemsTableSelectGrouped->group('order_id');
// Add our sub-select to main collection with only one column: name
$collection->getSelect()
->joinLeft(
['soi' => $itemsTableSelectGrouped],
'soi.order_id = main_table.entity_id',
['product_id', 'product_sku']
);

return $collection;
}
}
```

[image]